# Disable system beep on TSpinEdit when pressing Enter

Tags: delphi, beep

I have a default button on a form that has a TSpinEdit control on it. When the TSpinEdit control has the focus and the user presses the Enter key, instead of the default button getting clicked, the user just hears a system beep because the Enter key is invalid for a TSpinEdit.

Normally, to avoid the beep, I would use the OnKeyPress event and set the `Key := 0` to skip the key press. I could then execute the click method on the default button. However, in this case, OnKeyPress doesn't fire because the Enter key is not valid.

OnKeyDown fires, but when I set `Key := 0` there, it doesn't stop the system beep.

So, how do I disable the system beep when pressing the Enter key on a TSpinEdit control?

I'm on Delphi 5, and they didn't include the source for Spin.pas.

Comment: Did you look in "<Program Files>\Borland\Delphi5\Source\Samples\" ?

Comment: @Uwe, thanks! That's exactly where spin.pas is. I guess I had a file search fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to descend from `TSpinEdit` and override `IsValidChar` to avoid the MessageBeep call or `KeyPress` to avoid `IsValidChar`.

Comment: This is what I did, of course, though thanks to Uwe for helping me find the source!

Answer (score 8):

Try this one

```
//Disable system beep
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETBEEP, 0, nil, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE); 

//Enable system beep
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETBEEP, 1, nil, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

Comment: thanks for the great info, but I still want to hear the beeps for the other invalid keys, so if I wait until the OnKeyDown event fires before I disable the system beep, it doesn't seem to prevent the beep.

Comment: −1. This is a global "solution" to a local problem. This will affect other applications as well. Don't do this.

Answer (score 6):

Set KeyPreview = True on your form and add the following code to the form's keypress event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if SpinEdit1.Focused and (Key = #13) then
  begin
    Key := #0; // Cancels the keypress
    Perform(CM_DIALOGKEY, VK_RETURN, 0); // Invokes the default button
  end;
end;
```